# Python Monty Hall: Multiprocessing slower than direct processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, simulation

I am trying out multiprocessing for my Monty Hall game simulation for improved performance. The game is payed 10mm times and takes ~17 seconds when directly run, however, my multiprocessing implementation is taking significantly longer to run. I am clearly doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.

```
import multiprocessing
from MontyHall.game import Game
from MontyHall.player import Player
from Timer.timer import Timer


def doWork(input, output):
    while True:
        try:
            f = input.get(timeout=1)
            res = f()
            output.put(res)
        except:
            break


def main():
    # game setup
    player_1 = Player(True) # always switch strategy
    game_1 = Game(player_1)

    input_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    output_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # total simulations
    for i in range(10000000):
        input_queue.put(game_1.play_game)

    with Timer('timer') as t:
        # initialize 5 child processes
        processes = []
        for i in range(5):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=doWork, args=(input_queue, output_queue))
            processes.append(p)
            p.start()
        
        # terminate the processes
        for p in processes:
            p.join()

        results = []
        while len(results) != 10000000:
            r = output_queue.get()
            results.append(r)

    win = results.count(True) / len(results)
    loss = results.count(False) / len(results)

    print(len(results))
    print(win)
    print(loss)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my first post. Advice on posting etiquette is also appreciated. Thank you.

Code for the Classes:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, switch_door=False):
        self._switch_door = switch_door

    @property
    def switch_door(self):
        return self._switch_door

    @switch_door.setter
    def switch_door(self, iswitch):
        self._switch_door = iswitch

    def choose_door(self):
        return random.randint(0, 2)

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, player):
        self.player = player

    def non_prize_door(self, door_with_prize, player_choice):
        """Returns a door that doesn't contain the prize and that isn't the players original choice"""
        x = 1
        while x == door_with_prize or x == player_choice:
            x = (x + 1) % 3  # assuming there are only 3 doors. Can be modified for more doors
        return x

    def switch_function(self, open_door, player_choice):
        """Returns the door that isn't the original player choice and isn't the opened door """
        x = 1
        while x == open_door or x == player_choice:
            x = (x + 1) % 3  # assuming there are only 3 doors. Can be modified for more doors
        return x

    def play_game(self):
        """Game Logic"""
        # randomly places the prize behind one of the three doors
        door_with_prize = random.randint(0, 2)

        # player chooses a door
        player_choice = self.player.choose_door()

        # host opens a door that doesn't contain the prize
        open_door = self.non_prize_door(door_with_prize, player_choice)

        # final player choice
        if self.player.switch_door:
            player_choice = self.switch_function(open_door, player_choice)

        # Result
        return player_choice == door_with_prize
```

Code for running it without multiprocessing:

```
from MontyHall.game import Game
from MontyHall.player import Player
from Timer.timer import Timer


def main():

    # Setting up the game
    player_2 = Player(True)  # always switch
    game_1 = Game(player_2)

    # Testing out the hypothesis
    with Timer('timer_1') as t:
        results = []
        for i in range(10000000):
            results.append(game_1.play_game())

        win = results.count(True) / len(results)
        loss = results.count(False) / len(results)

        print(
            f'When switch strategy is {player_2.switch_door}, the win rate is {win:.2%} and the loss rate is {loss:.2%}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How do we reproduce your results? You have not provided all your code.

Comment: Please, also add a code sample of how you do that without multiprocessing

Answer (score 1):

<s>As you did not give the full code that we can run locally, I can only speculate.</s> My guess is that you are passing an object(a method from your game) to other processes so pickling and unpickling took too much time. Unlike multithreading where you can "share" data, in multiprocessing, you need to pack the data and send to the other process.

However, there's a rule I always follow when I try to optimize my code - profile before optimizing! It would be much better to KNOW what's slow than GUESS.

It's a multiprocessing program so there are not a lot of options in the market. You could try `viztracer` which supports multiprocessing.

```
pip install viztracer
viztracer --log_multiprocess your_program.py
```

It will generate a `result.html` that you can open with chrome. Or you can just do

```
vizviewer result.html
```

I would suggest to reduce the iteration number so you can have a view of the whole picture(because viztracer uses a circular buffer and 10 million iterations will definitely overflow). But, you can still get the last piece of your code executing if you don't, which should be helpful enough for you to figure out what's going on.

I used viztracer as you gave the whole code.

[image]

This is one of your iteration in your worker process. As you can tell, the actual working part is very small(the yellow-ish slice in the middle `p...`). Most of the time has been spent on receiving and putting data, which eliminates the advantage of parallelization.

The correct way to do this is do it in batches. Also as this game does not actually require any data, you should just sent "I want to do it 1000 times" to the process, and let it do it, instead of sending the method one by one.

There's another interesting problem that you can easily find with viztracer:

[image]

This is the big picture of your worker process. Notice the large "nothing" in the end? Because your worker needs a `timeout` to finish, and that's when they are waiting. You should come up with a better idea to elegantly finish your worker process.

Comment: Thank you. Although not exactly what I was looking for your answer helped me see the bigger picture and arrive at the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Updated my code. I fundamentally misunderstood the multiprocessing method.

```
def do_work(input, output):
    """Generic function that takes an input function and argument and runs it"""
    while True:
        try:
            f, args = input.get(timeout=1)
            results = f(*args)
            output.put(results)
        except:
            output.put('Done')
            break


def run_sim(game, num_sim):
    """Runs the game the given number of times"""
    res = []
    for i in range(num_sim):
        res.append(game.play_game())
    return res


def main():
    input_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    output_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    g = Game(Player(False))  # set up game and player
    num_sim = 2000000

    for i in range(5):
        input_queue.put((run_sim, (g, num_sim)))  # run sim with game object and number of simulations passed into
    # the queue

    with Timer('Monty Hall Timer: ') as t:
        processes = []  # list to save processes
        for i in range(5):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_work, args=(input_queue, output_queue))
            processes.append(p)
            p.start()

        results = []
        while True:
            r = output_queue.get()
            if r != 'Done':
                results.append(r)
            else:
                break

        # terminate processes
        for p in processes:
            p.terminate()

    # combining the five returned list
    flat_list = [item for sublist in results for item in sublist]
    print(len(flat_list))
    print(len(results))
```